# how to get single value from comma separated array when fetching data from MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am entering data in data base like this:

```
ID | Name | Email   | Place
1  | Khan | abc@... | Page1, Page2, Page10
```

Now I am fetching data like this :

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM story Where Place='Page2' Limit 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

But unfortunately it show me nothing :(

I am uploading this `Place` row in comma separated form, now I want it show me the data where I select place.

Comment: What do you want to be returned? Do you want any value where Page2 is in an comma separated array?

Comment: There is no column named `phone` according to sample data. You could use `like` if `phone` = `place`. You probably should separate out each one into its own record.

Comment: you didn't even include the code where you try to display anything

Comment: This value will show on different pages, like If I want to show this data on page 1 (Home Page), Page 4 and Page 7  I will select page1, page4, page7. Now on page1, page 4 and page 7 it will show.

Comment: kind of looks like you want `SELECT * FROM story Where Place like '%Page2%' Limit 1";`

Comment: NOT working for me :( `mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given`

Comment: data really should be normalized and place be given its own table

Comment: Is the column `phone` or `place`? I'd consider using a regex for this so Page20 doesn't equal Page2. With regex it'd be something like `Page2(,|$)`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please consider normalizing your data.  [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad) The design you have here will make you crazy if your application actually grows.

In the meantime, you want to use `column LIKE '%value%'` in place of `column = 'value'`. Beware: the performance of this kind of query is very bad and can't be improved.

**EDIT** Queries using `column = 'value'` or even `column LIKE 'value%'` can exploit indexes in the database management system. It's possible to look up values in an index in O(log(n)) time. That permits even a vast table, with billions of rows, to be accessed efficiently. However, a query containing `column LIKE '%value%'` has to scan through all the data, row by row, exhaustively looking for matches, in O(n) time.  If you have a few hundred rows you won't notice this poor performance. But if your table grows you will definitely be sorry.

Try this query.

```
     SELECT * 
       FROM table
      WHERE column LIKE CONCAT('%' , 'Page2', '%')
      LIMIT 1
```

I suggested the use of `CONCAT()` so the query can easily be modified to use bind parameters.  For example, `CONCAT('%' ,? , '%')`

**Another edit.** If you have `Page1, Page100, Page101` you'll get a lot of false positive matches on `Page1`.  [In MySQL `FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) can do a search of a comma-separated string.

```
     SELECT * 
       FROM table
      WHERE FIND_IN_SET('Page2', column) <> 0
      LIMIT 1
```

This will not work if you have spaces after your commas. `Page1,Page2,Page3` is fine, but `Page1, Page2, Page3` is no good. We can patch that problem like so.

```
     SELECT * 
       FROM table
      WHERE FIND_IN_SET('Page2', REPLACE(column, ', ', ',')) <> 0
      LIMIT 1
```

But now things are getting out of hand. What if you have two spaces after a comma someplace? Or three?

This too is an unoptimizable search.

Comment: amazing ! Clap for you. Its work for me. But why this query is bad and can't be improved ?

Comment: or if there is to many values like 200+ or I want to get only one like above. So can I use this query ?

Comment: what happens at page20 21 etc

Comment: nice link Ollie. can't even get to 1NF :>

Comment: @user3396968 `LIKE %page2%` will match `page2` or `page20` or `page21` or `page200` etc

Comment: @Dagon, this strategy falls apart very quickly indeed. I suppose one could use RLIKE and a regular expression. But, grumble,

Comment: @OllieJones we all know the *real* answer is to normalise

Comment: I can't get that, how can I normalize my data?

Comment: with a junction table. Someone wanna take a whack at it ?

Answer (score 1):

A move toward data normalization.

A proposed junction table (eradicates the Place CSV column):

```
create table story_place_jnc
(   -- one row per story/place combo
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    storyId int not null,
    place varchar(20) not null  -- you size this thing

    -- perhaps 2 FK's go here (1 to story, 1 to place):

    -- Unique composite key on (storyId,place):
);
```

As Patsy said in Monty Python's Holy Grail, "It's only a model."

Who knows if you even have a `place` table :>